# React classNames override className added by Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem that is When I adding class by JS method: `divElement.classList.add('className')`, but when I have state or props updated -> I decorate my component with a class just like below:

```
<div className={clsx(
            'chat-input-container',
            chatBoxInputCommandMode !== MODE.NORMAL && 'command-mode'
        )}/>
```

Then, classes which I added by JS method disappeared.
That is a problem of react or I do something wrong?
Anyone can explain why? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the components is recalculated/reevaluated on each re-render unless its memoized (ie. `useMemo`, `useCallback`) or is using React state/hooks like `useState` or `useEffect`.

Therefore, although you were able to modify the class name with javascript that doesn't cause a re-render, the `clsx()` will be reevaluated in the next render, so whatever you did with the class name via vanilla Javascript code won't be relevant.

I would recommend keeping using `clsx` to add/remove any class names, and moving the logic into a `useEffect` or storing the value into a `useState`.